# Selecting/Manuplating cells based on their location in the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as below

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
```

I want to multiply every 3rd column after the 2 column in the last 2 rows by 5 to get the ouput as below.

How to acomplish this?

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
1   10  3   4   25  6   7   40  9
1   10  3   4   25  6   7   40  9
```

I am able to select the cells i need with `df.iloc[-2:,1::3]`
which results in the df as below but I am not able to proceed further.

```
B   E   H
2   5   8
2   5   8
```

I know that I can select the same cells with `loc` instead of `iloc`, then the calcualtion is straign forward, but i am not able to figure it out.
The column names & cell values **CANNOT** Be used since these change (the df here is just a dummy data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign back to same selection of rows/ columns like:

```
df.iloc[-2:,1::3] = df.iloc[-2:,1::3].mul(5)
#alternative
#df.iloc[-2:,1::3] = df.iloc[-2:,1::3] * 5
print (df)
   A   B  C  D   E  F  G   H  I
0  1   2  3  4   5  6  7   8  9
1  1   2  3  4   5  6  7   8  9
2  1   2  3  4   5  6  7   8  9
3  1   2  3  4   5  6  7   8  9
4  1   2  3  4   5  6  7   8  9
5  1  10  3  4  25  6  7  40  9
6  1  10  3  4  25  6  7  40  9
```

Comment: too fast. cannot compete :O

Comment: I tried that but it did not work (on my actual df). Now when i check it is becsue the datatype is 'object'! Thanks anyway.

Comment: @moys you probably just need `astype(int)` on your columns

Comment: @moys - Then use for convert selection `df.iloc[-2:,1::3] = df.iloc[-2:,1::3].astype(int).mul(5)` or `df.iloc[:,1::3] = df.iloc[:,1::3].astype(int)` for convert columns

Comment: @anon01 I cannot do that since there is text inbetween. What i did was do assign float after selection & multiply by 5 like so --> `(df.iloc[-2:,1::3]).astype(float)*5`

Comment: @jezrael I was typing as you posted :-)